# How do I cause the click of one element to toggle the visibility of another element in Angular 4?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to let users show/hide a row of details by clicking the item row. I have a table of log entries. For each log entry row, there is a hidden row beneath it with detailed information. When a log entry row is clicked, the visibility of the details row should be toggled.

I initially solved this entirely in the event handler by crawling the DOM and modifying the style of the details row. That didn't feel very idiomatic to Angular, so after some digging I now have this solution:

The relevant HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of log; let i=index">
        <tr class="log-entry" (click)="displayRow[i] = !displayRow[i]">
            <td class="datetime">{{entry.datetime}}</td>
            <td class="actor">{{entry.actor}}</td>
            <td class="summary">{{entry.summary}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="details" [style.display]="displayRow[i] ? 'table-row' : ''">
            <td colspan="3">
                <pre>{{entry.details}}</pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

And the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LogEntry } from '../log';
import { LogService } from '../log.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log',
  templateUrl: './log.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log.component.styl']
})
export class LogComponent implements OnInit {
  log: LogEntry[]

  // Used by the template to keep track of which rows have details toggled
  displayRow: boolean[] = []

  constructor(private logService: LogService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logService
      .getLog()
      .then(this.onLogUpdated)
      .catch(this.onLogUpdateError)
  }

  // Event handlers

  private onLogUpdated = (log: LogEntry[]) => {
    console.debug("Redrawing log")

    this.displayRow = log.map((x) => false)
    this.log = log

    console.log(this.displayRow)
    console.log(this.log)
  }

  private onLogUpdateError = (error) => {
    console.error("Error when trying to get log from log service")
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

As you see I have to maintain an array of booleans to keep track of the state of the details row. I feel like it should be possible (and idiomatic) to accomplish this just in the template, I just don't know how to do it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit further through the Angular 4 guide I found a method that seems much nicer. It involves tagging the details row using a [`template reference variable`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars), then calling a function to hide the row using that variable:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let entry of logToday; let i=index">
<tr class="log-entry" (click)="toggleRow(details)">
    <td class="datetime">{{entry.datetime}}</td>
    <td class="actor">{{entry.actor}}</td>
    <td class="summary">{{entry.summary}}</td>
</tr>
<tr #details class="details">
    <td colspan="3">
        <pre>{{entry.details}}</pre>
    </td>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

It still requires a function to be defined in the component code:

```
// Toggles the visibility of a table row
toggleRow(row) {
  if (row.style.display == '') {
    row.style.display = 'table-row'
  }
  else {
    row.style.display = ''
  }
}
```

But at least it's much cleaner than my previous approach.

Note: My toggle function is written that way because the details row is hidden by default.